# find which template is used in given website?

Tags: templating

I want same template which is used in http://www.rideicon.com/ this website...is there any way to find which template is used in given website?

Answer (score 4):

Craft CMS does not really have ready to use templates. This is why you should not be able to find any references to that. In difference to Wordpress, etc. – usually these are hand-crafted. Is this what you were asking?